# In apa.cls [man] mode, how do you get the table to go with text?

Tags: tables, floats, apa-style, apa6

My table consistently skips to the very last page! Is this simply a function of the `doc` mode? I have tried various float controlling methods like `\FloatBarrier`, etc., but nothing has been successful so far.

On the [TUG website](http://tug.org) it says:

> When revising and proofreading a manuscript, it is most helpful to
>   have the tables and figures readily available (rather than turning
>   most of the way to the end of the manuscript to access them). If the
>   user invokes the `floatsintext` option (in the `\documentclass` line),
>   tables and figures will be integrated in the text approximately at the
>   point where they are mentioned.

I tried this but maybe I read it wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `apa6` class is designed to produce documents according the very strict (and somewhat wacky) APA standards for submission.  Since the APA requires all tables and figures to be at the end, this is what the class does.  However, the `floatsintext` option should do what you want:

- `floatsintext`  In man mode, integrates floats (tables and figures) within the body of the text instead of postponing them until after the reference list.

So use:

```
\usepackage[man,floatsintext]{apa6}
```

or

```
\usepackage[doc,floatsintext]{apa6}
```

Both should work.

If this doesn't work for you, you will need to reduce your example to a minimal one that shows the problem.

You can find the full documentation for the `apa6` class by using the `texdoc` utility (if you are using a TeX Live system). Depending on your editor, there may be an interface to it built in to the editor as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! How come the normal float positioning commands do not work in the apa class?

Comment: @melanie The package loads the `endfloat` package which messes with the float processing in major ways.  Since it's designed to meet the APA standard for submission, allowing the regular float mechanisms doesn't make much sense.  I haven't tested whether they in fact work if the `floatsintext` option is used.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,natbib]{apa6}
```

Comment: Please do not only post a line of code, explain what it does to solve the given problem. Welcome to TeX.SE!